# Weird behaviour by the geometry manager of tk/tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to set the width of a window, to do this I use the code:

```
wm geometry .sigsetting_menu [regsub {\d+x} [wm geometry .sigsetting_menu] {463x}]
```

To set it to be 463 pixels wide. But when I run only this line, the height of the window is set to 1. If I ran before that line the command `puts` with any argument, even an empty string with no new line, which does nothing:

```
puts -nonewline ""
```

Then I get the correct result, i.e. the window have height which is not 1. What causes it, and how can I fix the issue?

---

<sup>Comment about proper coding standrts:</sup>

<sup>I'm aware that I'm using a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) here, and that it's a very bad practice. This is a temporary solution for the problem that I have, in the future the "magic number" will be replaced with a value that is calculated according to the relation of the window to other windows in the frame, but the code will be the same only that `463` will be replaced with `$width`</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tk postpones window creation, *geometry calculations* (which can be rather complex and mostly rather pointless during the setting up of a window's contents) and actual drawing of the contents until the application is *idle*, that is until it is in the event loop and there are no pending real events to process. (Timer events aren't pending in this sense until they fire.) This is normally the right thing to do: it makes Tk seem very fast for almost all normal code. All this processing is handled using a concept called an “idle event”, which Tk uses a lot of internally, and which you can make your own with via `after idle`.

**However,** a consequence of the previous paragraph is that you can't do what you want directly; at the time you ask for the current information about the window's geometry, it's not been computed yet so you get some (irrelevant) defaults. You could force the flushing of the pending idle processing (with `update idletasks`, which is often abbreviated to `update idle`) but that can cause some tricky problems with reentrancy and it also triggers unsightly flashing of the display (because of the mapping and drawing, which you can't also prevent). Because of that, what you *actually* should do is postpone your geometry adjustments themselves until their own idle event, like this:

```
after idle {
    wm geometry .sigsetting_menu [regsub {\d+x} [wm geometry .sigsetting_menu] "463x"]
}
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing, use a helper procedure to keep your code simple and `list` to generate the callback (it does exactly the right quoting).

```
proc setGeometryWidth {window width} {
    wm geometry $window [regsub {\d+x} [wm geometry $window] "${width}x"]
}
after idle [list setGeometryWidth .sigsetting_menu 463]
```

---

Also, are you sure it is wise to set the width to an explicit number of pixels? High resolution displays are coming…

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show where you're creating that window i'm guessing you're doing not long after creating it, something like:

```
toplevel .sigsetting_menu
wm geometry .sigsetting_menu [regsub {\d+x} [wm geometry .sigsetting_menu] {463x}]
```

The problem is that it takes time to create the window and it happens in stages (i'm not an expert on this so I'm sure the exact process), first it's creating the window and only then resize it, but TCL works "too fast" so it calls the second line before it resize the original window so the height remains 1px but the width changes. But when you call something like `puts` which takes time then it manages to resize the window properly.
The correct way to do that we would be to call a special command for such cases called  [`update`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/update.htm) which stops the execution of the current code until the event loop is empty.
So you should do something like:

```
toplevel .sigsetting_menu
update idle
wm geometry .sigsetting_menu [regsub {\d+x} [wm geometry .sigsetting_menu] {463x}]
```

Comment: The window is created quite a lot before the command, infact the command is the last command in the proc. But your solution works. Please edit it so to not be "only" for windows created right before the command.

Comment: Actually you could bind your resize to something like visibility or Configure events of the widget, which is preferable to forcing the update.